# website benchmaking tool with automatic mail support

Tags: jmeter, benchmarking

I'm looking out for a tool that supports recording option in web on the tasks that I perform (search and result analysis).

I finally rerun the recorded script and calculate the time that is taken for each page that is loaded (generally based on the search criteria) within the web.

Once the page loading exceeds the defined time, the exceeded time should be highlighted.

The reports on this should be automatically saved.

The above scenario was tried using jmeter, but I was not able to set benchmark and automatically set the scenario as failed when the page load exceeds the defined number.

Please suggest a tool that could be used for the above mentioned scenario, and if the same could be done using Jmeter that I'm missing out.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter you have :

1. [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) which you can utilize to set the response time threshold. If response time exceeds the time set in the duration assertion JMeter will automatically mark the relevant sampler(s) as failed
2. [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) which can be used for sending JMeter test results to the specified recipient(s). Add a [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan (tearDown Thread Group is being executed **after** all other Thread Groups), put SMTP Sampler under this tearDown Thread Group and configure it to send .jtl results file at the end of the test. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for example configuration.